# Using printf in C, how do you print an equation containing multiplication and cosine?

Tags: c, printf

Recently I made a pretty simple physics work calculator in C++. It would request the distance, force and angle of the force, store them as doubles and then output them after calculating them in the following equation -

`distance * force * cos(angle * M_PI / 180.0)`

Now, I decided to remake it in C, and I believe I am almost done, but I don't know use `printf()` to output the result of that equation. Simply putting the equation in the parentheses of `printf` gives the following error: ***argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type***. Help would be appreciated, thank you

This is the line of code that I'm having trouble with: `printf(distance * force * cos(angle * M_PI / 180));`, and `distance` in particular is the one that is giving the error. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

note: I am aware of the existence of tags such as `%lf`, which I used when storing the user inputs, but I do not know how to apply them when outputting that equation, or if they are even necessary when outputting in general.

Comment: You want `printf("%f\n", distance * force * cos(angle * M_PI / 180));`

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is **always** a format string. Check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: **C and C++ are different**. Recommendation: read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) then [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) then the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: yes, I know they are different. if you said this because of how the post was labeled, it was probably because I included the c++ tag - I'll remove it. if it was because how I phrased it, then like I said, I know that they're different, but I'm still new to both of them, but even worse at C than C++ - in C++ "cout" was all you needed 

Answer (score 1):

to this specific question, the solution came from a comment by user @pmg -
`printf("%f\n", distance * force * cos(angle * M_PI / 180));` is what worked. Thank you!